# Appropriate signal to kill django development server

Tags: django, linux, process

I'm trying to send a signal to the django development server to kill the parent and child processes.

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4.1, using settings 'myproject.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

$ ps axf
26077 pts/12   Ss     0:00  \_ -bash
 4189 pts/12   S+     0:00  |   \_ python manage.py runserver
 4194 pts/12   Sl+    0:00  |       \_ /myproject/.virtualenv/bin/python manage.py runserver

$ kill -s SIGINT 4189
$ ps axf
4194 pts/12   Sl     0:00 /sh/myproject/.virtualenv/bin/python manage.py runserver
```

My understanding is that SIGINT should emulate pressing Ctrl-C in the terminal, but notice that SIGINT terminates the parent, 4189, but not the child, 4194. Same behavior for SIGKILL, SIGTERM, SIGSTOP. Using Ctrl-C from the terminal kills both as expected.

Is there a way to terminate the parent in a way that also kills the child without knowing the child's PID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put a dash in front of the process, this should kill the process group.

```
 kill -s SIGINT -4189
```

Answer (score 9):

`kill -9 4189`

Have a try, it should work!

Comment: "Is there a way to terminate the parent in a way that also kills the child?"

I'm hoping to indirectly kill the child by killing the parent only. I'm attempting to run the django dev server supervised using the runit suite without using --noreload.

Comment: @Aaron, This answer worked for me but the accepted answer didn't

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem but accepted answer didn't work on my CentOS:

```
$ ps fx | grep [p]ython
30864 pts/0    S      0:00 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
30866 pts/0    Sl     0:00  \_ /var/webapp/venv/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
$ kill -s SIGINT -30864
-bash: kill: 30864: invalid signal specification
```

So, I found this solution:

```
$ pkill -P 30864
$ ps fx | grep [p]ython
$ # empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pkill`:

```
$ pkill -f "python3 manage.py runserver"
```